# If Nav links is more than 10 show Hamburger menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a navbar that if my nav links is more than 10, even if not in mobile a hamburger icon will appear. Because if the nav links all displayed the nav bar becomes messy and the others wont fit.

this is the code for my nav bar right now

```
            <div class="main-menu-toggle">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>

           <div id="site-header">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location'  => 'main-menu',
                'container'       => 'nav',
                'container_class' => 'site-main-menu-container',
                'menu_class'      => 'site-main-menu uninitialized',
                'menu_id'         => 'main-menu',
            ) );
            ?>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count ul li length by `length`.

Try with the below code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if ( jQuery('#main-menu ul li').length > 10 ) { 
        jQuery('.your-hamburger-class').show();
    }
});
```